# How run flutter 'packages pub run build_runner build' with debug mode in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart, build-runner

I want to put break point on my generator code, but I don't know how to run the command on the debug mode.

I wrote generator using `source_gen` and `build_runner`

```
class MyGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<Todo> {
  @override
  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    return "// Hey! Annotation found!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. run commad `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`*
2. copy `build.dart` to root folder of project

[image]

3. add new run configuration
   [image]
4. run debug, now you can debug your code generator!

---

* the `packages` is optional, you can just run `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a side note though, make sure your "Working directory" points to the root path of flutter project where "pubspec.yaml" is located.

Comment: You don't actually have to copy the file to the root of the project. Just open the file in Android Studio and place a breakpoint in it. Then debug the project as a Dart Command Line App with `Dart file` set to the path of the file, eg `/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-2.1.7/lib/src/entrypoint/build.dart`. You can copy **Absolute Path** using the Android Studio project tab

Answer (score 1):

Ivan's answer worked for me, but every time I changed a file that was using an annotation - the build process outputted:

```
[SEVERE] Terminating builds due to build script update
[INFO] Terminating. No further builds will be scheduled
```

and then renamed the build script itself from `build.dart` to `build.dart.cached`, and then exit with code 75.

After digging through the `build_runner` code, I discovered that this behavior can be mitigated by using the following Program Arguments:

```
serve --skip-build-script-check
```

(i.e. instead of just `serve` as Ivan suggested).

There may be some negative consequences; in the `build_runner` source code, in `options.dart`, I saw this:

```
// For testing only, skips the build script updates check.
bool skipBuildScriptCheck;
```