# How to debug flutter build_runner build in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, build, code-generation, build-runner

**Problem statement:**

I am building a code generator with the [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) package.

I run `flutter pub run build_runner build` to execute my code generators.

**Question:**

How can I debug `flutter pub run build_runner build` with breakpoints?

**Similar questions:**

[How run flutter 'packages pub run build_runner build' with debug mode in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628425/how-run-flutter-packages-pub-run-build-runner-build-with-debug-mode-in-intelli)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since I found [How run flutter 'packages pub run build_runner build' with debug mode in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628425/how-run-flutter-packages-pub-run-build-runner-build-with-debug-mode-in-intelli) I was wondering how this works in VS Code. Furthermore, I didn't liked the solution with copying the build file. This is how i got it working.

## Generating the script:

The first thing to do is executing `flutter pub run build_runner build` so the files in the `.dart_tool` folder are generated. My app is called `meal_app`.

[image: Folder structure]

The code generator script is located in `.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart`.

### Running the script:

The script can be run with `dart .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart build` but that is just executing, not debugging the script. For convenient debugging the VS Code `launch.json` needs to be adjusted.

## Create a `launch.json`

The `launch.json` file configures the launch configurations in VS Code. To create a `launch.json` select the debug symbol on the right and create the `launch.json` file.

[image: Create a launch.json]

## Create a launch configuration for build_runner

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Config 1
        },
        {
            // Config 2
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Widgetbook Generator",
            "cwd": "example/meal_app",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": ".dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["build"]
        }        
    ]
}
```

`cwd:` [Probably not required] The app for which `build_runner` is generating files is called `meal_app`. The `meal_app` is located in a subfolder called `example`. Thats why the `cwd` property is set in the configuration. If your app is not located in a subfolder, you can omit this option.

`args:` Set to "build". This is similar to the command `flutter pub run build_runner` *`build`* where *`build`* is the argument of `build_runner`.

`program:` Since the code generator file is located in the structure mentioned above, the configuration needs to know which file to execute.

`name:` This is the name of the configuration.

Don't forget to switch to the correct configuration

Comment: I have a slightly different requirement. My debugger enters the `.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart` file, and my breakpoints there work. However, how do I get my breakpoints in the actual code generator that I wrote to work?

Comment: no. i haven't figured out how to get that working.. let me know if you figure it out!

Comment: Remove `cwd` field works for me.

Comment: Thank you @Jens. Awesome hint and this is why I love SO.